# Save & retrieve multiple image byte[] code in datagridview to SQL Server using XML C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, datagridview

I am creating first one data table to save images in datagridview.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));//0
 dt.Columns.Add("Upload", typeof(string));//1
 dt.Columns.Add("Show", typeof(string));//2
 dt.Columns.Add("image", typeof(byte[]));//3

 for (int i = 0; i < dgvDemo.RowCount-1; i++)
 {
            DataRow drOLD = dt.NewRow();
            drOLD["image"] =dgvDemo.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
            drOLD["Name"] = dgvDemo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
            drOLD["Upload"] = "Upload";
            drOLD["Show"] = "Show";
            dt.Rows.Add(drOLD);
 }

 Image img = PBImage.Image; //Image.FromFile(@"physical path to the file");
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr["image"] = imageToByteArray(img);
 dr["Name"] = "Image";
 dr["Upload"] = "Upload";
 dr["Show"] = "Show";
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);

 dgvDemo.DataSource = dt;

 public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
 {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
 }
```

This is the code saving images in database using XML as parameter for stored procedure

```
 hash = new Hashtable();
            hash.Add("@QueryNo", QueryNo);
            string strXmlCategory_Section = "";
            StringBuilder xmlClassMaster = new StringBuilder();
              for (int k = 0; k < dgvDemo.Rows.Count-1; k++)
                {
                    xmlClassMaster.Append("<Row>");
                    xmlClassMaster.Append("<Name>" + dgvDemo.Rows[k].Cells[0].Value + "</Name>");
                    xmlClassMaster.Append("<GridImage><cdata>" + ((byte[])dgvDemo.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value) + "</cdata></GridImage>");
                    xmlClassMaster.Append("</Row>");
                }

                if (xmlClassMaster.Length > 0)
                {
                    xmlClassMaster.Append("</ImageInGrid>");
                    strXmlCategory_Section = "<ImageInGrid>" + Convert.ToString(xmlClassMaster);
                }
                hash.Add("@strImageInGrid", strXmlCategory_Section);
```

hash table is passing as parameter list to the stored procedure.

Stored procedure code:

```
Exec sp_xml_prepareDocument @DocHandle_ImageInGrid output, @strImageInGrid

select Name, GridImage
        into #temp 
        from OPENXML (@DocHandle_ImageInGrid, '/ImageInGrid/Row',12)
        with (

                Name varchar(50) 'Name', 
                GridImage varbinary(max) 'GridImage'

             )

    insert into dbo.GridImage
        ( Name, GridImage)
    Select  Name, GridImage
    From #temp
```

I have a problem in fetching the image from database & it to Grid.

Error is

> parameter is not valid. at system.drawing.image.fromstream

I think that my save method is wrong please help

Comment: Just to be clear, `((byte[])dgvDemo.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value` is the value returned by `imageToByteArray()`?

Comment: yes.i this covert image to byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `imageToByteArray()` can return bytes with any value from 0 to 255.  It's likely that your database does not support strings with such entirely arbitrary character values.  Suggest that you instead convert the image bytes to base 64:

```
    public static string ToBase64String(this System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        if (imageIn == null)
            return null;
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])converter.ConvertTo(imageIn, typeof(byte[])));
    }

    public static Image FromBase64String(string imageString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageString))
            return null;
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(Convert.FromBase64String(imageString));
    }
```

I used `ImageConverter` because it saves the image in its current format.  If you want to save the image to a specific format -- `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif` in your case -- your code is correct.

**Update**

It looks as though you are making a more fundamental error.  When you do

```
var s = "<GridImage><cdata>" + ((byte[])dgvDemo.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value) + "</cdata></GridImage>";
```

You are basically doing

```
byte[] byteArray = (byte[])dgvDemo.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;
var s = "<GridImage><cdata>" + byteArray + "</cdata></GridImage>";
```

To perform this addition, .Net converts `byteArray` to a string by calling its `ToString()` method -- but this method has not been overridden in arrays and simply returns the type name.  Thus you get `"<GridImage><cdata>System.Byte[]</cdata></GridImage>"`, which is surely not what you want.  You need to convert the byte array to a string explicitly, which [`Convert.ToBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do for you.

Comment: @Ranjeet - I don't know what data type you should use in your database, I'm not a DBA.  But if you want your XML to contain regular ASCII that can be parsed by anyone, I recommend you convert your image to base 64 encoding.   Also, see update about a more fundamental bug in your code.

Comment: @Ranjeet - by the way, if you use a `MemoryStream`, you should dispose of it afterwards via the `using` statement: `using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {  }`.  See the examples in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).